# How to disable/enable different query optimizations in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I'm doing some test to see the capability of Postgresql query performance. And my plan is to disable/enable different query optimizations, such as disable (automatic) index, disable re-order joins   etc. is there some configuration to achieve this quickly or what part source code should I revise? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL provides debug parameters for exactly this.

See [the `enable_` params](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE) in the docs.

Please don't use them in production; it might seem like a good idea at the time, but those settings won't adapt as the data changes and grows, so what starts out as a performance win will probably become a problem later.