# Disable PostgreSQL query optimization?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-12

I have come across the need to totally disable PostgreSQL query optimization just so that I can measure the effectiveness of applying QO (I want to see a before and after). I have come across this topic [How to disable all optimizations of PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857855/how-to-disable-all-optimizations-of-postgresql)  from 2014 which basically says it's not possible. I wonder if anything has changed since then? I would really like to see a bad plan vs good plan scenario with a dramatic difference.

Answer (score 3):

You can't execute a query without a plan, and the optimizer is what comes up with the plan.  There is no "default" plan which would exist in the absence of the optimizer.

You turn all the `enable_*` parameters to off, except for `enable_seqscan` and `enable_nestloop`.

Or you could set `join_collapse_limit` and `from_collapse_limit` both 1, that would severely constrain what the optimizer can do.